# Creating an irregular arc with python turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm trying to make a function which draws an irregular arc similar to *figure 1*, instead it has drawn a spiral. I'm not sure how to draw one correctly and there are no functions to do this to my knowledge

[Long Arc - Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cP3Tx.png)

```py
import turtle
char = turtle.Turtle()
char.speed(0)
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.tracer(False)


def draw_arc(length, left_right):
    sx = char.xcor()
    sy = char.ycor()

    def turn(angle):
        if left_right:
            char.left(angle)
        else:
            char.right(angle)
    count = 1.8
    turn(90)
    char.forward(1)
    while char.xcor() != sx and char.ycor() != sy and count >= 0:
        char.forward(1)
        turn(1 * count)
        count -= 0.01


draw_arc(100, True)
screen.update()
turtle.listen()
turtle.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Pen(visible=False)


t.speed('fastest')
t.left(90)
for x in range(180):
    t.forward(1)
    t.right(1)
```

> add this line and modify it until it fit ur need ( setx() or sety )

```
    t.setx( x * 1.5)
```

Comment: Although that arc is similar, it isn't the same. The arc I would like to print is wider than that while maintaining the same height.

Comment: i will update my answer then